# CSS conditional statement for "if not IE7" not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```
<!--[if !(IE 7)]>
    <link href="/assets/css/fixed.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```

This isn't working. I'm working with Chrome and it's not picking up anything in the style sheet I referenced. I'm trying to add a style sheet that gets loaded in everything EXCEPT IE 7 as I'm trying to implement some UI changes that IE 7 doesn't support very well.

Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: [there's a better way to manage IE-specific styles](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/).

Comment: Simply put, IE is the only browser that reads these comments.  Chrome, firefox, safari etc. simply see them as an HTML comment, and ignore them.

Comment: Conditional comments are exclusively an Internet Explorer crapzore.  I cannot call them a feature, so crapzore seems like a reasonable substitute.

Comment: Got it, what I'm trying to do isn't possible. I figure out another solution, thanks.

Comment: @DwB +1 for "crapzore". I wonder how that's trending...

Comment: @Scott I'm not sure what your problem is that you are solving, but you could target chrome with some javascript and UserAgent sniffing.  That said...  If you are targeting Chrome specifically for some reason, there is probably a better way to fix your issue than to target chrome independently from other browsers.  Its generally a bad idea to target specific browsers anyways for various reasons, the one exception is IE, because IE is terrible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These only work in IE. So your style sheet should apply to IE8+ and IE6-, but not IE7. All other browsers simply see this as a code comment and ignore it, hence why you're not getting the stylesheet in Chrome.

I should add also that this is not CSS, it's HTML.

```
<!-- -->
```

These (above) are html comments. Anything within them is ignored by the rendering engine. IE on the other hand has "special" logic to look for these "IE 'version'" style comments. These exist because older versions of IE are generally incompatible with the rest of the world! :)

One more thing I'd like to add is that nowadays it's not generally considered (sorry, no reference) good practice to write browser detection but rather feature detection.

There are libraries that exist to help you write cross browser compatible Css and Js. For example: [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) respectively.

Comment: he might also look for it in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx)

Comment: So bottom line is what I'm trying to do isn't possible because the comments are only picked up in IE. I've only ever used conditional comments to target specific versions of IE, didn't realize other browsers didn't pick them up...

Comment: @Scott. Yes, only IE understands them. There are libraries that exist to help you write cross browser compatible Css and Js. For example: [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) respectively.

Answer (score 1):

try w/o the parenthesis. like:

```
<!--[if !IE 7]><!-->
<h1>You are NOT using IE7</h1>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

(tho' your code should be working as well)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
<!--[if IE 7 ]><link href="#" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE7]>--><link href="#" /><!--<![endif]-->
```

Your example, Chrome is only viewing a comment, it does not parse ie conditional html.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<!--[if !IE7]>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<![endif]-->
```

or if greater than IE7 use default stylesheet

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<![endif]-->
```

but I think it's best to write separate IE7 styles.

Comment: That won't work for what I'm trying to do, which is load a style sheet for ALL browsers except IE 7 (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE8+, etc)